# Compare two columns in excel with different lengths

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have two columns in Excel, with different length.  They contain links to SharePoint sites.

I need to make a comparison, so that in column C, I would like to get all the links that exist in column A and not B.

In column D I would like to get all the links that exist in column B and not A.

To clarify, in the C and D column I want the link values, and not any true, false or 0 or 1.

As it's links I don't see how any test data would help to be posted here but in case you need it, leave a comment and I'll put something together as I cant post the company links here.

Comment: i think you can do this with partial string match vlookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$39,MATCH($A1,$B$1:$B$39,0))),A1,"")`.
This will return all of the values that are exclusively in Column A. You can adjust the formula to return only values that are in Column B.